# Having trouble creating tables using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm learning MySQL at the moment and I am attempting to create a Database and some tables. I'm getting an error with two of the tables and for the life of me can't see what I am missing.

The two tables which throw an error are:
MAINTANANCE_REPAIR
and
TRIP.

If anyone could spot what I am missing it would be incredibly helpful. Thanks!

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS CTSDB30091479;
use CTSDB30091479;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LANGUAGE(
  LanguageCode CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
  LanguageName VARCHAR(50)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COUNTRY(
  CountryCode CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
  CountryName VARCHAR(50)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COUNTRY_LANGUAGE(
  CountryCode CHAR(2),
  LanguageCode VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(CountryCode, LanguageCode),
  FOREIGN KEY(CountryCode) REFERENCES COUNTRY(CountryCode),
  FOREIGN KEY(LanguageCode) REFERENCES LANGUAGE(LanguageCode)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOCATION_TYPE(
  LocTypeID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  LocTypeDescription VARCHAR(40)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOCATION(
  LocationID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  StreetNo VARCHAR(5),
  StreetName VARCHAR(50),
  City VARCHAR(30),
  LocTypeID INT,
  FOREIGN KEY(LocTypeID) REFERENCES LOCATION_TYPE(LocTypeID)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DRIVER(
  DriverLicenseNum VARCHAR(18) PRIMARY KEY,
  DriverFirstName VARCHAR(20),
  DriverLastName VARCHAR(20),
  ClearenceLevel CHAR(1),
  HasSecurity CHAR(1),
  HasFirstAid CHAR(1),
  IsAvailable CHAR(1)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DRIVER_LANGUAGE(
  LanguageCode CHAR(2),
  DriverLicenseNum VARCHAR(18),
  PRIMARY KEY(LanguageCode, DriverLicenseNum),
  FOREIGN KEY(LanguageCode) REFERENCES LANGUAGE(LanguageCode),
  FOREIGN KEY(DriverLicenseNum) REFERENCES DRIVER(DriverLicenseNum)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CERTIFYING_BODY(
  CertBodyID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  CertBodyName VARCHAR(18)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DRIVER_SECURITY(
  DriverLicenseNum VARCHAR(18) PRIMARY KEY,
  CertBodyID INT(50),
  SecurityLevel CHAR(1),
  CertDate DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY (DriverLicenseNum) REFERENCES DRIVER(DriverLicenseNum),
  FOREIGN KEY (CertBodyID) REFERENCES CERTIFYING_BODY(CertBodyID)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DRIVER_FIRSTAID(
  DriverLicenseNum VARCHAR(18) PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstAidLevel CHAR(1),
  FirstAidDate DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY (DriverLicenseNum) REFERENCES DRIVER(DriverLicenseNum)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VEHICLE(
  VIN CHAR(17) PRIMARY KEY,
  VEH_Make VARCHAR(30),
  VEH_Model VARCHAR(30),
  VEH_Colour VARCHAR(20),
  VEH_RegoNum CHAR(6),
  VEH_Odometer INT(6),
  VEH_Availability CHAR(1),
  VEH_SeatCapacity INT(2)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MAINTANANCE_REPAIR(
  VIN CHAR(17),
  OdometerReading INT(6),
  MR_Type CHAR(1),
  MR_Date DATE,
  MR_Cost DECIMAL,
  MR_Details VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY(VIN, OdometerReading),
  FOREIGN KEY(VIN) REFERENCES VEHICLE(VIN),
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OFFICIAL_ROLE(
  RoleID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  RoleDescription VARCHAR(40)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OFFICIAL(
  OfficialID CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  LanguageCode CHAR(2),
  CountryCode CHAR(2),
  OfficialFirstName VARCHAR(40),
  OfficialLastName VARCHAR(40),
  OfficialRole INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (LanguageCode) REFERENCES LANGUAGE(LanguageCode),
  FOREIGN KEY (CountryCode) REFERENCES COUNTRY(CountryCode),
  FOREIGN KEY (OfficialRole) REFERENCES OFFICIAL_ROLE(RoleID)
)
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRIP(
  BookingRefNum INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  VIN CHAR(17),
  DriverLicenseNum CHAR(18),
  OfficialID CHAR(8),
  PickUpLocID INT,
  DropOffLocID INT,
  StartTimeIntended DATETIME,
  EndTimeIntended DATETIME,
  StartTimeActual DATETIME,
  EndTimeActual DATETIME,
  StartKM INT(6),
  EndKM INT(6),
  FOREIGN KEY (VIN) REFERENCES VEHICLE(VIN),
  FOREIGN KEY (DriverLicenseNum) REFERENCES DRIVER(DriverLicenseNum),
  FOREIGN KEY (OfficialID) REFERENCES OFFICIAL(OfficialID),
  FOREIGN KEY (PickUpLocID) REFERENCES LOCATION(LocationID),
  FOREIGN KEY (DropOffLocID) REFERENCES LOCATION(LocationID),
)
Engine=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On both tables you have an extra comma at the last line of the table definition:

```
FOREIGN KEY(VIN) REFERENCES VEHICLE(VIN),
                                        ^ here

FOREIGN KEY (DropOffLocID) REFERENCES LOCATION(LocationID),
                                                          ^ and here
```

Remove it and you'll be happy.